# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting this error Trying to get property of non-object.

This is my controller

```
public function onGoingOrder($orderNumber)
{
    $orderNumber = westcoorder::where('id', $orderNumber)->firstOrFail();

    $items = westcoorderitem::where('westcoorder_id', $orderNumber)->first();

    return view('westco.onGoingOrder', compact('orderNumber', 'items'));
}
```

This is what is in my view

```
<div class="panel-heading">Order {{ $orderNumber->id }} Items</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @foreach ($items->westcoorderitems as $item)
                <li>{{ $item }}</li>
            @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my two models

```
class westcoorder extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'westcoorders';
    protected $with = 'westcoorderitems';

    protected $fillable = ['is_sent', 'is_delivered'];

/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
    public function westcoorderitems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\westcoorderitem');
    }
}

class westcoorderitem extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'westcoorderitems';

    protected $fillable = ['westcoorder_id','quantity', 'productName', 'productCode', 'price'];


    public function westcoorders()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\westcoorder');
    }
}
```

And i keep getting that error when i trying to list all the items within the order with the `Order_id`

Here is what my tables looks like

```
Schema::create('westcoorders', function (Blueprint $table)
{
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->tinyInteger('is_sent')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('is_delivered')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
} );

Schema::create('westcoorderitems', function (Blueprint $table)
{
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->Integer('westcoorder_id'); // fk for westcoOrder.id
        $table->string('quantity');
        $table->string('productName');
        $table->string('productCode');
        $table->decimal('price');
        $table->timestamps();
} );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In the last releases of Laravel a lot of things changed under the hood. With the release >= 5, Models are not loaded automatically in your application. In your controller, under the namespace {yournamespace}; statement, reference the classes you need with the use statement this way:

```
use App\westcoorders
```

Just an advice about the conventions: the respect of the conventions is always a good practice. Your models should be called WestCoorder and WestCoorderItem (notice the CamelCase naming of the classes). This concept is valid for your controller too (WestCoordersController and WestCoorderItemsController)

Comment: I've have already got this `use App\westcoorder;` in my controller and i still get the error

Comment: Ill also start using CamelCase So i should have it like this `WestcoOrderItems` and `WestcoOrder`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check if `$orderNumber` does exist before you use it:

```
@if ($orderNumber)
    {{ $orderNumber->id }}
@endif
```

Next, you're trying to iterate `$items->westcoorderitems`, but:

- It's not a collection, since you're using first() method. It returns one instance, so you shouldn't iterate it.
- I can't see `westcoorderitems` column in your `westcoorderitems` table, so you shouldn't try to use `$items->westcoorderitems` here.
- You should also check if `$items` is not empty, before you use it.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Order @if ($orderNumber) {{ $orderNumber->id }} @endif Items</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @if ($items)
            {{ $items->productName }}
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did have it like that but i was getting this as an error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$productName` and i still am??

Comment: That means your query doesn't returns any results. Try to use `dd($items)` before `{{ $items->productName }}` to know if it has `productName`.

Comment: So I'd its returning no results. That mean the relationship between the two databases is not working